# how to get (this) element's parent index and pass it as a value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the following example,how would i get the parent `<ol>` index inside the wrapper div and pass it as a value in the li's innerText ?
tried something like $(this).closest("ol").index() but did'nt work

```js
$("li").text("this ol's index is " + $(this).closest("ol").index());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<ol><li class="li"></li></ol>
<ol><li class="li"></li></ol>
<ol><li class="li"></li></ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not in any event handling or callback context here, so `$(this)` simply refers to the `window` object (wrapped in jQuery.)

Go through the `li` in a loop, then `$(this)` will have the proper context inside the callback function.

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  $(this).text("this ol's index is " + $(this).closest("ol").index());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<ol><li class="li"></li></ol>
<ol><li class="li"></li></ol>
<ol><li class="li"></li></ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```